# How to deploy a distributed system across multiple servers in parallel using VSTS release process

Tags: deployment, parallel-processing, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

Here's my scenario, I have a list of task groups in Visual Studio online as such which take in parameters of MachineName (the target server):

```
Task1
Task2
Task3
Task4
```

And a group of servers:

```
SVR1
SVR2
SVR3
SVR4
```

At present, I have a deployment pipeline that effectively says (all on the same agent using the [None] Parallelism option):

```
Task1(SVR1)
Task1(SVR2)
Task1(SVR3)
Task1(SVR4)

Task2(SVR1)
Task2(SVR2)
Task2(SVR3)
Task2(SVR4)
etc...
```

These tasks must be executed in a specific order and no task should start on any server until all servers have received the previous task. The current deployment process is however not particularly scale-able. Every time we add an additional node, it adds around 1min 20s to deployment time.

What I want to do is:

```
Execute Task1 on all servers (Wait until all are complete)
Execute Task2 on all servers (Wait until all are complete)
Execute Task3 on all servers (Wait until all are complete)
etc.. you get the picture.
```

I've currently not found an example online that is exactly what I need and I don't have much experience in using VSTS to deploy in parallel.

Is there an easy way of doing this? Do I need to run multiple agents to get this to work or can it run several parallel tasks on the same agent?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you explain the reason why you want to execute task1 on all servers and then execute task2 etc? Since you are deploy on different servers, shouldn't you deploy to the servers separately (such as execute task1 on SVR1 but not execute task1 on SVR2, then execute task2 on SVR1 shouldn't be wait)?

Comment: @MarinaLiu-MSFT - it's a distributed Orleans application that runs on multiple nodes.

Task1 is 'stop all services'.

Task2 is then 'uninstall all old services'.

Task3 - 'copy new files to servers'

Task4 - 'install all new services'. That's why we want to execute them in order.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Orleans. But if you truly want to deploy the four tasks to different servers sequently, you should add 16 tasks in you release definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add multiple agent phases for each task group (task1, task2 etc...):

1. Add a variable to store servers (e.g. name: `servers`; value: `SVR1,SVR2,SVR3,SVR4`)
2. Add multiple agent phases for each task groups (task1, task2 etc…)
3. Configure execution plan for each agent phase (select a phase > Check Multi-configuration option > Specify `servers` (step1 variable) in Multipliers input box
4. Then you can get a server from `servers` variable in task

On the other hand, you can configure multiple agents in the same machine and pool, then specify agent number in Maximum number of agent input box of each phase to decrease the build/release time.

Comment: Ok - I have a task group that takes the following parameters: RemoteComputer, Username, Password. Because the task group runs a powershell script. Is it possible to 'pass' the server/remote computer name into the parallel task groups from the agent phase multiplier.

Comment: My task group: https://i.imgur.com/nr2jsxk.png. My agent phase: https://i.imgur.com/OIHZjUL.png. My variables: https://i.imgur.com/fRPpQCo.png. How can I specify in the agent phase, a set of multipliers that I wish it to run in parallel by filling in the 'remote computer' parameter in the task group with the different values.

Comment: @Seb 1. Specify `services` variable with SVR1,SVR2,SVR3,SVR4 value 2. Specify `services' in multipliers 3. Specify $(services) in RemoteComputer box. The agent pool must has more than one agent in order to run multipliers in parallel.

Comment: Fantastic, all done and running in parallel now! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Since you only have a single pipeline, tasks will execute serially not concurrently.

If you want to deploy a task concurrently among different servers, you should buy additional pipelines.

Comment: Hi sorry I think I misworded. I have a single pipeline, with 1 agent phase, and 42 tasks. The problem is this executes them in order (in serial). What I want to do is make = Agent phase to execute Task 1 on all servers, Agent phase to execute Task 2 on all servers. But I want to wait between those. Is this possible with multipliers and variables?

Comment: You can use multipliers, but it works similar as the your current situation since you have only one pipeline, so all the tasks are execute serially. Such as task1 won't execute concurrently among the different servers.